# Permutation with bash - Spread Five over Eight

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

Assuming I have the values `A B C D E` and eight places `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`. How can I get all possible combinations printed with two- and three-time repetitions?

**Example:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
_______________
A A B B C C D E
A B B C C D D E (and so on...)
A A A B B C D E
A B B B C C D E (and so on...)
```

Which combination is followed by which is not further important. There should not be any missing values like `AABBCCDD` *(where `E` is missing)*

Comment: What exactly is your problem? 1. Finding an algorithm? 2. Implementing the algorithm in `bash`? If 1 then ask about the algorithm first. If 2 then show the algorithm (or a link to it) in the question. I think this question is not specifically related to UNIX or Linux and might better fit on https://stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude approach with `zsh`/`ksh93`/`bash` could be:

```
printf '%s\n' {A..E}{A..E}{A..E}{A..E}{A..E}{A..E}{A..E}{A..E} |
  sed '/A/!d; /B/!d; /C/!d; /D/!d; /E/!d; /\(.\)\(.*\1\)\{3\}/d'
```

Where we use zsh-style `{A..E}` to generate all 5<sup>8</sup> combinations from `AAAAAAAA` to `EEEEEEEE`, and `sed` removes the ones that don't contain `A`, or don't contain `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` or more than 3 of the same character.

Add `;s/./ &/2g` (GNU `sed`) or `;s/./ &/g;s/ //` (any `sed`) to the `sed` code to insert spaces in-between the letters.